# Can a familiar use master abilities while in a Familiar Tattoo?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e, familiars, cantrips

[Familiar Tattoo](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=998) is a magic item from Secrets of Magic, and your familiar can crawl into it. While it doesn't mention either master or familiar abilities, the latter mostly need movement or interaction from the familiar, so it is obviously out.
However, I see no reason why the familiar could not provide an extra cantrip for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Probably yes

The rules on Familiar Tattoo are pretty sparse, and do not state explicitly any limitations about what the familar can or cannot do or affect:

> Your familiar can **meld into your familiar tattoo to be carried in your skin**. The familiar must spend a single action, which has the magical, move, and transmutation traits, to meld into or exit your tattoo. It must be adjacent to you to meld into your tattoo, and it exits your tattoo in an open space adjacent to you. Any of the familiar's companion items remain on it, but it can't carry any other items with it.

That's it. I think you are right that in the absence of anything that says they cannot provide an effect, and where the effect does not require their physical presence in some way, a good default assumption would therefore be they can, wether melded, or not.

This would include Master Abilities like [Cantrip Connection](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=13) or [Spell Battery](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=17) which have no requirmements about the familiar being in a defined location or using any kind of action.

#### Actions and Space

I think it is less clear for things that require an action by the familiar, like [Restorative Familiar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=71). While melded into the tatoo, can it take actions? Nothing explicitly states it can not. I think this is a call for the DM.

Likewise, while melded, does it count as being "in your space"? It is in a tatoo on your skin after all. The rules for [space](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=445) say "Creatures and objects of different sizes occupy different amounts of space." and "Multiple Tiny creatures can occupy the same square. At least four can fit in a single square", but I would think while melded, the familar is part of the tatoo, and does not occupy any amount of space in that sense. Again, I think probably a call for the DM.

Answer (score 2):

### The Familiar can Take Any Action

> Your familiar can meld into your familiar tattoo to be carried in your skin.

All the tattoo mentions is that a familiar can meld into or exit the tattoo, with no limitation that they can't take other actions or provide constant benefits or relevant traits like [extradimensional](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=67). Their only limitation would be the inherent one of location, that they're in your skin until they decide to exit the tattoo.

They're not in some other plane so abilities like [Restorative Familiar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=71) or [Touch Telepathy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=36) would work without issue, but they likely wouldn't be able to easily target creatures other than you with your skin in the way.